# Combining two VBA terms that use Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("rngBarcodeInput")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
            Application.Undo
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        Range("DJ5").Copy
        Range("rngBarcodeInput").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("rngShipCheckInputFieldsNoBarcode").ClearContents
        Range("rngEditStatus").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I want to add this code below into the VBA but only works when I remove the above since they both use Worksheet_Change. All the combinations combining into one Private Sub haven't worked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("C7")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Range("C15").Value = Range("B15").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Second code won't work since it will cause to fire event which it handles.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work, on the assumption that you DON'T want the changing of C15's value to cause the other event to fire..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("rngBarcodeInput")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
            Application.Undo
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
        Range("DJ5").Copy
        Range("rngBarcodeInput").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("rngShipCheckInputFieldsNoBarcode").ClearContents
        Range("rngEditStatus").ClearContents
    End If

    Set KeyCells = Range("C7")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Range("C15").Value = Range("B15").Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("rngBarcodeInput")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
            Application.Undo
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        Range("DJ5").Copy
        Range("rngBarcodeInput").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("rngShipCheckInputFieldsNoBarcode").ClearContents
        Range("rngEditStatus").ClearContents
    End If

    ' no need for extra variable, just check address directly
    'Dim KeyCells As Range
    'Set KeyCells = Range("C7")

    If Target.Address = "$C$17" Then Range("C15").Value = Range("B15").Value

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Just put code of both methods together.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers appear to be correct, there may be instances that would would want to keep the two routines apart, as it adds additional flexibility and ease of debugging.

You can do this by *renaming* the two existing routines to whatever you'd like, then make a third routine that handles the change event and calls upon the two separate subs.

In this example, we will rename to `sub1` and `sub2`, but obviously you can change to something that provides a better description.

---

The routine that will handle the change event. You simply call `Sub1` & `Sub2`, and pass the same argument that was obtained by the event, `Target`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    sub1 Target
    sub2 Target

End Sub
```

Your original routines, renamed:

```
Private Sub sub1(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("rngBarcodeInput")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
            Application.Undo
            Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If

        Range("DJ5").Copy
        Range("rngBarcodeInput").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Range("rngShipCheckInputFieldsNoBarcode").ClearContents
        Range("rngEditStatus").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub sub2(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("C7")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    Range("C15").Value = Range("B15").Value

End Sub
```

A major benefit with this is that if you have multiple worksheets that you wanted to use your code for, you could copy your two routines into a standard module. Then each sheet would have the `Worksheet_Change()` event calling these routines.
If you ever had to modify either of those two subs, you would only need to do it once instead of having to go sheet by sheet making the update.